# VxWorks signals

Tags: vxworks

I have a question regarding previous question asked in VxWorks forum.
My goal is when the high priority function generates a signal the low priority function will handle it immidiately(the high priority function must be preempted)

The code is:

```
sig_hdr () { ... }
task_low_priority() {
    ...
    // Install signal handler for SIGUSR1
    signal(SIGUSR1, sig_hdr);

    ...
}

task_high_priority() {
    ...
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1); //pid is the ID of task_low_priority
    ...
}
```

After  the line:
 `signal(SIGUSR1, sig_hdr);` 
i added 
`taskDelay(0)`.
I wanted to block the high priority task so the low priority task can gain  the CPU in order to execute the signal handler but it does not happen unless i do `taskDelay(1)`.

Can any one explain why it does not work with `taskDelay(0)`?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, taskDelay(0) will not let lower priority tasks run because of the following:

1. high priority task is executing
2. high priority task issues taskDelay(0)
3. Scheduler is invoked and it scans for the next task to run, it will select the highest priority task that is "ready"
4. The task that issued the taskDelay(0) is ready because the delay has expired (i.e. 0 ticks have elapsed)
5. So the high priority task is rescheduled immediately, in this case taskDelay(0) is effectively a waste of CPU cycles.

Now in the case where you issue taskDelay(1) the same steps are followed, but the difference is that the high priority task isn't in the ready state because one tick has not elapsed, so a lower priority task that is ready can have 1 tick of CPU time then it will be preempted by the high priority task.

Now there are some poorly designed systems out there that do things like:

```
taskLock();
...
taskDelay(0);
...
taskUnlock();
```

With the intention of having a low priority task hog the CPU until some point where it then allows a high priority task to take over by issuing a taskDelay(0). However if you play games like this then you should reconsider your design.

Also in your case I would consider a more robust system, rather than doing a taskDelay() to allow a low priority task to process an event, you should send a message to a low priority task and have that low priority task to process the message queue. While your high priority task blocks on a semaphore that is given by your event handler or some thing similar. In this situation you are hoping to force a ping pong between two different tasks to get a job done, but if you add a queue that will act as a buffer, so as long as your system is schedulable (i.e. there is enough time to respond to all events, queue them up and fully process them) then it will work.

---

**Update**

I assume your system is supposed to be something like this:

1. Event occurs (interrupt driven?).
2. High priority task runs to gather data.
3. Data is processed by low priority task.

If this is the case the pattern you want to follow is actually quite simple, and in fact could be accomplished with just 1 task:

Interrupt handler gathers data, and sends a message (msgQSend()) to task.
Task is pending on the message queue with msgQReceive.

But it might help if I knew more about your system (what are you really trying to do) and also why you are using posix calls rather than native vxworks calls.

---

If you are new to real time systems, you should learn about Rate monotonic analysis, there is a very brief summary on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling

Also note that in VxWorks a "high priority" is 0, and "low priority" is 255, the actual numbers are inversely related to their meaning :D

Comment: Hey,First thanks for the answer. I still cant understand somthing,suppose i have 2 tasks in my system one with high priority and one with low. I want to send messages from the high priority task to the low priority task as you suggested via message queue. After a high priority task sent a message in to the queue in order to read the message the low priority task has to be scheduled, this is exactly the point i dont understand how the low priority task will get some CPU time when the high priority task is running?

Comment: Updated post, maybe you can give more details about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

> > this is exactly the point i dont understand how the low priority task will get some CPU time when the high priority task is running?

High priority task will continue run till it gets blocked. OInce it gets blocked, lower priority task that are ready run will run.

Answer (score 0):

My answer has 2 parts:
1.  How to use correctly task Delay with vxWorks
2.  TaskDelay is not the correct solution for your problem

### First part:

TaskDelay in vxWorks can confused:

taskDelay(0) – don't perform delay at all!!!

It is a command to the scheduler to remove the current task from the CPU. If this is still the highest priority task in the system, it will return to the head of the queue with no delay at all. You will use this command if the scheduler configured to FIFO in case tasks in the same priority and your task have a CPU real time consumer function to run, the can try to release the CPU for other tasks in the same priority (nice).

BTW, it is the same as taskDelay(NO_WAIT).

TaskDelay(1) – this will delay the calling task sometime between zero (!!!) to 1 system tick. The delay in vxWorks finish at a round system tick.

TaskDelay(2) – sometime between 1 system tick to 2 system ticks.

3 …… (understood…)

TaksDelay(-1) (A.K.A taskDelay(WAIT_FOREVER)) – will delay the task forever (not recommended).

### Second part:

Using taskDelay to enable low priority task might be  a wrong idea. You didn't provided the all problem information but please note that delaying the high priority task will not ensure your low priority task will run (regardless the sleep time you'll write). Other tasks in highest priority from your high & low priority tasks might run for the all 'sleep time'.
There are several synchronized methods in vxWorks, like binary semaphores, changing task priority, signals, …